# Download a File with Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Does elisp have a function that takes a url and a destination and downloads that url off the internet?

I've discovered `url-retrieve` and `url-retrieve-synchronously` but `url-retrieve` takes a callback and `url-retrieve-synchronously` puts everything into a buffer. Is there anything simpler?

Comment: If you just want to get the remote file into an Emacs buffer, `browse-url-emacs` is handy.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try `url-copy-file`.  Its description reads,

> url-copy-file is an autoloaded Lisp function in `url-handlers.el'.
>
> (url-copy-file url newname &optional ok-if-already-exists keep-time)
>
> Copy url to newname.  Both args must be strings.
>   Signals a `file-already-exists' error if file newname already exists,
>   unless a third argument ok-if-already-exists is supplied and non-nil.
>   A number as third arg means request confirmation if newname already exists.
>   This is what happens in interactive use with M-x.
>   Fourth arg keep-time non-nil means give the new file the same
>   last-modified time as the old one.  (This works on only some systems.)
>   A prefix arg makes keep-time non-nil.

Comment: I had to ```require 'url``` to use ```url-copy-file```

Comment: (For Emacs newbies)
If you want to use this like `wget` (i.e. not as a part of a program or function) you can type `ESC :` (which prompts for an elisp expression to eval) then type: `(url-copy-file "http://example.com/" "filename.txt")`

Answer (score 12):

Obviously `url-copy-file` is the best option, but to the more adventurous Emacs hackers I'd suggest something like this:

```
(require 'url)

(defun download-file (&optional url download-dir download-name)
  (interactive)
  (let ((url (or url
                 (read-string "Enter download URL: "))))
    (let ((download-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously url)))
      (save-excursion
        (set-buffer download-buffer)
        ;; we may have to trim the http response
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (re-search-forward "^$" nil 'move)
        (forward-char)
        (delete-region (point-min) (point))
        (write-file (concat (or download-dir
                                "~/downloads/")
                            (or download-name
                                (car (last (split-string url "/" t))))))))))
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go for a custom download path. I tried url-copy-file but couldn't get it to work on Windows since it was using the emacs directory concatenated with whatever download name I gave it. With this code it downloads to any given folder, no problem. Extremely useful on a windows machine with no programming environments installed except emacs, heh.

Answer (score 4):

```
(w3m-download "http://www.gnu.org/index.html")
```

Comment: While this is true, `url-copy-file` works on platforms to which w3m hasn't been ported.

Answer (score 4):

http://steloflute.tistory.com/entry/Emacs-Lisp-urlretrieve

```
; synchronously    
(defun get-url (url)
  (with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously url) (buffer-string)))

(print (get-url "http://www.gnu.org"))

; asynchronously    
(defun print-url (url)
  (url-retrieve url (lambda (a) (print a))))

(print-url "http://www.gnu.org")
```

Retrieving URLs | http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/url/Retrieving-URLs.html

Current Buffer | http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html